# using multiple .csv files in single dygraphs chart

Tags: dygraphs

After some searching here I was unable to find a similar question to my problem. I am  new to the dygraphs library so please excuse me if this information is available somewhere.

I have multiple timeseries which based on user selection I want to display one, two, or all datasets together.  Is this possible with dygraphs?  My first thought was can multiple .csv files be used to create one chart, or can certain variables be toggled off/on in the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like [this demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/visibility.html), which lets you toggle the visibility of series. View source for inspiration.

It's possible to implement by combining multiple CSVs, but you'd have to write the merging code yourself. dygraphs draws charts, it doesn't manage your data for you.

Comment: Great, thanks. My thought about multiple CSV files was along the lines of an overplot type of functionality, not necessarily dygraphs merging the data itself. Either way, the toggle option is probably a better solution anyways.